# Sum two columns by identifier only between start and end dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Consider I have the below:

Dataframe:

```
id    enddate         startdate        ownerId   value
1     2019-10-05      2019-10-05       10        105 
2     2019-10-06      2019-10-05       10        240
3     2019-10-07      2019-10-05       10        420
4     2019-10-08      2019-10-08       10        470
5     2019-10-01      2019-10-01       11        320
6     2019-10-02      2019-10-01       11        18
7     2019-10-10      2019-10-10       12        50
8     2019-10-12      2019-10-10       12        412
9     2019-10-14      2019-10-10       12        398
10    2019-10-15      2019-10-12       12        320
```

What I would like to do is to sum all the "value" columns where the endId is between the current startId and the current endId for the same ownerId.

Output should be:

```
id    enddate         startdate         ownerId   value    output
1     2019-10-05      2019-10-05        10        105      105     # Nothing between 2019-10-05 and 2019-10-05
2     2019-10-06      2019-10-05        10        240      345     # Found 1 record (with id 1)
3     2019-10-07      2019-10-05        10        420      765     # Found 2 records (with id 1 and 2)
4     2019-10-08      2019-10-08        10        470      470     # Nothing else between 2019-10-08 and 2019-10-08
5     2019-10-01      2019-10-01        11        320      320     # Reset because Owner is different
6     2019-10-02      2019-10-01        11        18       338     # Found 1 record (with id 5)
7     2019-10-10      2019-10-10        12        50       50      # ...
8     2019-10-12      2019-10-10        12        412      462
9     2019-10-14      2019-10-10        12        398      860
10    2019-10-15      2019-10-12        12        320      1130    # Found 3 records between 2019-10-12 and 2019-10-15 (with id 8, 9 and 10)
```

I tried to use groupby.sum, etc. but I cannot get what I need...

Any advice on how you can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a **single** instruction:

```
df['output'] = df.apply(lambda row:
    df[df.ownerId.eq(row.ownerId) & df.enddate.between(row.startdate, row.enddate)]
    .value.sum(), axis=1)
```

Comment: Initially I missed this detail. Now I corrected my solution.

Comment: wow! I spent like 3hours trying to have this working (maybe too focus on a groupby solution which was the wrong way of thinking...) thank you for the very accurate and fast answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using selfjoin if the dataset isn't too big:

```
df[['startdate','enddate']] = df[['startdate','enddate']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

df['output'] = (df.merge(df, on='ownerId', suffixes=('','_y'))
                  .query('startdate <= enddate_y <= enddate')
                  .groupby('id')['value_y']
                  .sum()
                  .to_numpy())

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id    enddate  startdate  ownerId  value  output
0   1 2019-10-05 2019-10-05       10    105     105
1   2 2019-10-06 2019-10-05       10    240     345
2   3 2019-10-07 2019-10-05       10    420     765
3   4 2019-10-08 2019-10-08       10    470     470
4   5 2019-10-01 2019-10-01       11    320     320
5   6 2019-10-02 2019-10-01       11     18     338
6   7 2019-10-10 2019-10-10       12     50      50
7   8 2019-10-12 2019-10-10       12    412     462
8   9 2019-10-14 2019-10-10       12    398     860
9  10 2019-10-15 2019-10-12       12    320    1130
```

Comment: Many thanks. Indeed this works perfectly fine. I am still unsure of why we need to group by id, as the id is a unique key in my case

Comment: This merge "selfjion" solution will create multiple rows with the same ID because of the cartesian join.  So, inorder to get the sum, you need to group by ID.  @Valdi_Bo solution is much better.